# Binding database to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am  new to MVC and still learning my ways, and I am trying to fill up a drop down list. I have the following code (Model):

```
public class SchoolCodes
{
    public int escuelaCode { get; set; }
    public string escuelaName { get; set; }
}

public class AllSchoolCodes
{
    public List<SchoolCodes> GetSchools()
    {
        List<SchoolCodes> Codes = new List<SchoolCodes>();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MCE"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT EscuelaCode, EscuelaName from Escuelas", conn);
        conn.Open();
        using (var dataReader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {

                SchoolCodes ur = new SchoolCodes();
                ur.escuelaCode = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["EscuelaCode"]);
                ur.escuelaName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["EscuelaName"]);
                Codes.Add(ur);
            }

        }
        return Codes;


    }
}
public class GetSchoolCodeViewModel
{

    [Display(Name = "Escuela: ")]
    public int SelectedEscuelaCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllSchoolCodes { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCode()
    {
        var dbSchoolCodes = new AllSchoolCodes();
        var code = dbSchoolCodes
                    .GetSchools()
                    .Select(x =>
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.escuelaCode.ToString(),
                                Text = x.escuelaName
                            });

        return new SelectList(code, "Value", "Text");
    }


public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new GetSchoolCodeViewModel
        {
        AllSchoolCodes = GetCode()
        };
        return View(model);
     //   return View();
    }
```

Now, I am getting the following error back there in the Index controller : Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). I am stuck here and have absolutely no idea what to do. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypu don't need to create `SelectList`again as you are reutrning `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` , you can simply return `SelectList` this way:

```
private SelectList GetCode()
{
        var dbSchoolCodes = new AllSchoolCodes();
        var code = dbSchoolCodes.GetSchools();


        return new SelectList(code, "escuelaCode", "escuelaName");
}
```

or if you want to return `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` then you can do this way no need to create `SelectList` again:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCode()
    {
        var dbSchoolCodes = new AllSchoolCodes();
        var code = dbSchoolCodes
                    .GetSchools()
                    .Select(x =>
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.escuelaCode.ToString(),
                                Text = x.escuelaName
                            });

        return code;
    }
```